# how to use keyword new in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have used update trigger in my code shown below. It is triggering when i update user table. But it is not evaluating the condition what I have given new.salary>5000. I am getting names of all users. But I want name of a user whose salary is updated with the condition constraint.
Any ideas..

```
TRIGGER `t` AFTER UPDATE ON `User` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
Case
when new.salary > 5000 THEN

INSERT INTO newtable (name)
select name
from User
where new.salary>5000;
end case;
end
```

Comment: MySQL **or** SQL Server?

Comment: What do you want with `CASE` here?

Comment: What does "new" represent in your code?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL-Server you need to use `INSERTED` table to check rows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyFancyTrigger ON dbo.[USER]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT name
                    FROM INSERTED
                    WHERE Salary > 500 )
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO MyNewTable
                    (
                     name )
                    SELECT name
                        FROM INSERTED
                        WHERE Salary > 5000
        END
```

Full documentation on use of `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables in SQL-Server http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: you never specified what platform you are using.

Comment: Linux platform. Using phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that you mean [Oracle PL/SQL?](http://psoug.org/definition/NEW.htm)  Because in [keywords list of MS Sql  server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx), NEW is in the list of "future keywords that are planned to be implemented".
If you are trying to get the row that has been changed, you should use INSERTED and DELETED tables as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610966/how-to-get-updating-row-id-in-sql-server-trigger) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183703/identity-of-inserted-updated-row-in-trigger)